# HC-06 Bluethoot communication

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

During this week i purchased two hc-06 bluethoot module for arduino with the purpose of maintain a stable bluethoot connection between two arduino devices. Most people use hc-05 and hc-06 togheter so my question is if i can make a connection without hc-05 module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

What you have is two slave devices and you need a master in order to initiate the Bluetooth communication with the slave. So, either you need two HC-05 Or 1* HC-05 and 1* HC-06.

Comment: Sorry its not the answer you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You have purchased two slave modules (HC-06). Actually, you have to use a master module (HC-05) in order to initiate the Bluetooth communication.

Therefore, the answer to your question is NO ,  can not make a connection without HC-05 module, unless you provide any other master module.